# Is this Maz Kanata?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-phantom-menace

My wife and I were watching *The Phantom Menace* after watching *The Force Awakens*.  In the scene right before Anakin shows Padme C-3PO, it shows a clip of his room.  In that scene everyone has had the joy of seeing an Easter Egg of a weapon from the original Tron.
After seeing *The Force Awakens*, I noticed something else right next to it.  It looks like a tiny figurine of Maz Kanata.  Could this be?

[image: a still from that scene]

Comment: I don't have a source for this that would justify an answer, but it seems to me that this sculpture is inspired by various traditional sculptural styles from human history. For instance, the large, round head on a skinny neck evokes the sculpture of the Ashanti people, while the goggle-like eyes and curve of the legs remind me of Japanese _dogu_ statues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In-universe**: it's possible, though I have no idea why there would be a statue of a random cantina owner from a remote planet stuck amongst Anakin's belongings.

**Out-of-universe**: this is highly unlikely. *The Art of Star Wars: The Force Awakens* mentions that the character concept was created as a tribute to Abrams and Rick Carter's old teacher, Rose Gilbert. Seeing as that the character's concept was done some 15 years later and to evoke a specific person, it's unlikely that the character was also meant to reference a random statue in the background of Episode 1.

[image: Maz Kanata concept art]

For comparison, [a photo of the late Rose Gilbert](http://obits.dignitymemorial.com/dignity-memorial/obituary.aspx?n=ROSE-GILBERT&lc=4798&pid=168615156&uuid=a8f5fc70-c049-48c0-8b0e-bbc37ff3f3be):

[image]

Comment: Here is a picture of Rose Gilbert

![Rose Gilbert](http://ak-cache.legacy.net/legacy/Images/Cobrands/DignityMemorial/Photos/e3bf8224-1c7d-4f2c-976b-a529d034e791.jpg).

Comment: @Darktwin18 fantastic!

Answer (score 8):

The [official *Star Wars* Twitter account](https://twitter.com/starwars/status/795993035540668416) recently posted about this. It didn't confirm the statue to be of Kanata, but it did state that it's of an alien pirate, leaving the possibility open.

[image: Maz Kanata?]