# What references to the prequel trilogy are made in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, revenge-of-the-sith, the-phantom-menace, attack-of-the-clones

The Force Awakens makes many references to the original trilogy. What references to the prequel trilogy are made in The Force Awakens? I'm looking specifically for plot elements, characters, and even themes that are introduced in the prequels that appear in TFA. (Implicitly, has the new team dumped the prequel trilogy down the memory hole?)

Comment: I for one am happy to dump the prequels down the memory hole.

Answer (score 10):

Some references to the prequels in The Force Awakens are given [here](http://moviepilot.com/posts/3696275), including,

1. Flags from pod races being displayed outside of Maz Kanata's castle [image: pod racer flags]
2. "The Sith" are introduced into the films, but the term was introduced in the novelization of A New Hope.
3. There is a Jedi Temple in the prequels. The first Jedi Temple is mentioned in The Force Awakens.
4. Who the clones in the Clone Wars were.
5. Leitmotifs from the prequels.

It doesn't look like many references, and they're all oblique. If the prequels didn't exist, one's understanding of The Force Awakens wouldn't be different.

Comment: For #5, the article you cited is actually just saying the music has _similarities_ to the music from the prequels. None of the actual leitmotifs that are _from_ the prequels are heard in TFA.

Comment: The Imperial March is heard in the prequels as well as TFA - in-universe chronologically, that counts

Answer (score 3):

## Plots/characters

1. Weird-looking lightsabers

   This includes both the shapes - witness Maul's, and colors - witness Mace Windu's.

   In Episode 7 we have a Cross-Guard lightsaber, which is red/yellow in color according to WGA leaked script.
2. Slaughter of Jedi students by a Skywalker Turned Dark traitor

   Vader at Jedi Temple in E3 <=> Kylo Ren and Luke's trainees.
3. Protagonist being a best friend with alien restauranteur who's been around and knows stuff and is wise.

   Obi-Wan and his Ep2 friend [Dexter Jettster](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dexter_Jettster) discussing Camino <=> Han solo and Maz
4. The main goal.

   In OT, the main goal of the Bad Guys was to crush the Rebellion and keep on ruling; with a stretch goal of getting Luke to turn to Dark Side.

   In PT and in Ep 7, the main goal of Bad Guys is:

   - Destroy the Jedi

     > the sinister
     > FIRST ORDER has risen from
     > the ashes of the Empire
     > and will not rest until
     > Skywalker, the last Jedi,
     > has been destroyed.
   - Regain power from a position of defeat and emergence from hiding.
5. Heavy use of familial relationships to intertwine movies.

   OT merely had Skywalker family. Nobody else was related that I can think of.

   PT had Boba Fett's "father" Jango

   Ep 7 has Poe Damerron (parents fought for Rebellion), Snap Wexley (mother flew Y-Wing at Endor), Kylo Ren.
6. Rolling droids

   Droidekas <=> BB-8
7. Good Guys have a Senate (and the overall system of government) that is, basically, largely useless.

   Ironically, many of similar reasons which drove Separatists to separate away from the Republic, are the reasons Resistance arose outside of New Republic :)
8. Ewan McGregor's voice in Rey's vision as young Obi-Wan, alongside Yoda and Old Obi-Wan.
9. Maz Kanata [greatly resembles a toy found in Anakin's room](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111558/is-this-maz-kanata) (seemingly unintentional reference)

## Filming techniques

1. Motion capture CGI characters
2. In general, heavy use of CGI ([no matter what the PR was](http://www.slashfilm.com/force-awakens-visual-effects/))
3. Cockpit view of starfighter dogfights (we didn't see that in OT)

   Anakin in Ep1 <=> Poe

## If you also include canon materials beyond the film:

- In the Foster novelization, Snoke mentions that he witnessed the **rise** of the Empire - the concept not revealed as anything specific till the prequels.
- The basis of how the plot is set up is trade, taxation and politics

  Taxation of trade routes led to Trade Federation blocading Naboo.

  The trade chasing (according to Visual Dictionary) led the New Republic to demilitarize and refuse to confront First Order - which led to Resistance creation and to First Order's ability to become the menace.

Comment: 4 to 7 seem just a _little_ stretched to me :)  I think the OP means "canon introduced", not "concepts" or "visuals now possible due to CGI" :)

Comment: Points 1, 3, and 5 are the kind of thing I'm looking for. Even so, I'd bicker with you on point 5, as I don't think the prequels add much new on familial relationships that is reflected in TFA, but this is just my opinion.

Comment: Also, for me, the question came before finding the article, which I don't even think is all that great, but I think it's evidence that you have to look hard to find a connection between the prequels and TFA.

Comment: @AlexSzatmary - fair enough. You didn't quite phrase it in that way in the subject, though :)

Comment: Also the pulsing sound of the stasis pod Finn in placed in makes the same sound as the medical chamber Vader is in at the end of RotS.

Comment: @RedCaio - I must honestly admit I have no idea what pulsing you mean. Missed that one.

Comment: The sound at 2:23 after Vader crosses his arms in [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=5UnjrG_N8hU) is the sound heard at the end of TFA when Finn is recovering inside a stasis pod thingy.

Comment: Yoo-hoo! Downvotes!